# How do I write a relative path in SQLiteConnection function in C#?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I am stuck trying to find a way to make a relative connection string. Here is the absolute path to the db file:

`WordsConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\\Users\\me\\source\\repos\\WordsDataCore\\WordsDataCore\\words.db");`

It would be rational to suppose that the relative path must look like this:

`WordsConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=words.db");`,

in condition that the cs file and the db file have a common directory. But it doesn't work.

This doesn't work too:
`WordsConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=/words.db");`

The point is to make this connection work when launching a copy of the application on different machines. And of course I want different users to work with their own versions of the db file.

Comment: Pro tip: Put a `@` before the string to eliminate the need for double backslashes. e.g. `@"Data Source=C:\Users\me\source\repos\WordsDataCore\WordsDataCore\words.db"`

Comment: Do not hard code paths in your code. You have many ways in net to put your paths in some sort of configuration file, read and use them at runtime. Look for AppSettings section in config files. (or in case of connectionstrings the ConnectionStrings section)

Comment: String MYpath = @"whateveritis\WordsDataCore\" ;WordsConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + MYPath + "words.db");

Comment: `Data Source=words.db` does not mean "that the cs file and database file have a common directory". It means that the exe and db are in the same directory. `Data Source=/words.db` means that the db is in the root directory, like C:\.

Comment: Not sure if you found a solution but I've sorted mine with `string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory; string[] appPath = path.Split(new string[] { "bin" }, StringSplitOptions.None); connectionString = string.Concat("URI=file:",appPath[0], fileName);`